# Как расположить в recyclerview столько элементов, сколько уместится по ширине?

Tags: java, recyclerview

Стоит задача: сделать нулевой элемент в `recyclerview` в два раза больше, чем остальные. Делаю я это просто меняя для нулевого элемента `LayoutParams` в методе `onBindViewHolder` адаптера:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( width, height ) );
```

Для `recyclerView` использую `GridLayoutManager`:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), 2) );
this.adapter = new MyAdapter( this.getActivity() );
recyclerView.setAdapter( this.adapter );
```

Проблема состоит в том, что если так всё и оставить, в первой строке так и будет стоять два элемента. Задача же состоит в том, чтобы количество элементов в строке зависело от размера элементов.

[image: Необходимое расположение]

Пробовал [это решение](https://github.com/chiuki/android-recyclerview), ничего не изменилось, располагаются элементы всё ещё неверно.

Answer (score 1):

Всё же нашёл решение на просторах интернета. Правда, элементы располагаются не совсем в том порядке, но, если заморочиться, думаю, можно и это исправить. Я этого не делал, так как для задачи не важно расположение элементов, по крайней мере, пока.

Для динамического изменения количества столбцов использовал `SpanSizeLookup` в соответствии с кодом из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366412/gridlayoutmanager-setspansizelookup-creating-blank-cells) вопроса.

После применения этого метода у меня возникла проблема: для добавления расстояния между элементами я применял `android:layout_margin` в элементе, что при различном количестве столбцов давало разность в размерах строк и, соответственно, проблемы с выравниванием элементов. Для создания одинаковых отступов между элементами любого размера применил [это](https://gist.github.com/yqritc/ccca77dc42f2364777e1) решение.